# How to set referer header in Guzzle

Tags: php, http, guzzle

I'm trying to set the referer header on a guzzle request, but when I analyze the request Chrome developer tools, the referer header is not in the list of request headers. This is how I set the header:

```
 $headers = ['referer' => 'test.referer.com'];
    $guzzle = new Client([
        'defaults' => ['headers' => $headers]
    ]);
    $result = $guzzle->get('http://google.com');
    return $result;
```

I have tried multiple other solutions, but it's still not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Chrome? As in the client side browser? Guzzle? As in the serverside http client?

Comment: Oh man of course I won't see it there.. Don't program while stressed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

if it v6

```
$headers = ['Referer' => 'test.referer.com'];
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => $headers
]);
$result = $guzzle->get('http://google.com');
return $result;
```

You don't need strange param `default`

And need `Referer`. Not `referer`

Comment: You don't need to capitalize the R, at least I don't

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle (tested with 6.3) doesn't seem to be reliably passing on Referrer header set via headers. In general, you can always set raw curl options when you need to:

```
 $guzzle->get('http://google.com',[
     'curl' => [
          CURLOPT_REFERER => 'https://NotLiveYet.com'
      ]);
```

Comment: Careful, this does not work in PHP 8